# What does Oyzer-Dovidl's dream about Nechele mean in Singer's "The Riddle"?

Tags: short-stories, yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer

In Isaac Bashevis Singer's short story "The Riddle", Oyzer-Dovidl remembers a dream where his wife, Nechele, acted like a young boy:

> He was constantly remembering adventures from stories his aunts had read or told him, though now Nechele was involved in all of them. At night he dreamed of gipsy [sic] women, of robbers in caves, of sacks full of gold coins. Once it seemed to him that Nechele was male, that he saw under her lace drawers the fringed garment of a boy; but when he had tried to kiss her, she had clambered to the roof, nimble as a chimney sweep, and yelled down at him:
>
> *Kitchen cleaver*,
> *Pudding eater,*
> *Tumble down,*
> *Crack your crown.*
> <sub>"The Riddle", section 1 (translated by Chana Faerstein and Elizabeth Pollet)</sub>

How can this dream be interpreted? What does it mean that Oyzer dreamt that Nechele "seemed male", and that she was wearing the "fringed garment of a boy" (presumably *tzitzit*)?